# How to split a text using regex, but the splitted words continue keeping the regex separator?

Tags: java, regex, split, sentence

I have a text and using this simple regex to split it in words: `[ \n]`. It splits the text into words using spaces and line-breaks.

I want to know if there is a way to keep the whitespace or the line-break in the splited word, because I will use this to a simple sentence detection after some processing.

I'm using the `String#split` method.

Comment: Does your \n means something special (end of sentence)?  You are not processing normal paragraphs over multiple lines with "." as end of sentence?

Comment: @toto2 Punctuation is used too to determine the end of sentence, but the content comes from HTML content, so many sentences like title don't have punctuation determining where the sentences ends, only the line break.

Comment: I'm not sure you should rely on \n when processing HTML, since you could have a perfectly fine document without a single \n.

Comment: @toto2 The text I'm processing comes from the Boilerpipe API (an external HTML processor) and it contains the line breaks according the HTML content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use lookbehind as @Piotr Findeisen suggested (+1):

```
public class RegexExample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "firstWordWithSpaceAfter secondWordWithSpaceAfter wordWithLineBreakAfter\nlastWord";
    String sa[] = s.split("(?<=[ \\n])");
    for (String saa : sa )
        System.out.println("[" + saa + "]");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[firstWordWithSpaceAfter ]
[secondWordWithSpaceAfter ]
[wordWithLineBreakAfter
]
[lastWord]
```

Short explanation:

`?<=` is look behind, meaning you got a match if the data before the expression you are looking for is equal to the regex coming after `?<=` (in this case `[ \\n]`)

`[ \\n]` is regex that means **one of the characters** in the `[]`

so the whole regex says split every time that the character before the expression / word is either space or `\n`.

Since we didn't try to match space or `\n`, it will not remove them.

Comment: @Renato Dinhani Conceição - I am not a regex expert, but I hope he edit is clear enough.

Comment: You put your regex inside parenthesis. This is necessary?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, this is part of the lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Worked! :D

Answer (score 5):

Conside using zero-width positive lookbehind / lookahead. See [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) around *Special constructs (non-capturing)*

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to do something like this:

```
String myString = "Joe Blow\n1234 Fake Road\nHere, There, 12345";
String[] lines = myString.split("\\n");
Set<String[]> wordsByLine = new LinkedHashSet<String[]>();
for (String line : lines) {
  wordsByline.add(line.split(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really quickly off the top of my head, if the regex was always matching single characters, you could use the length to determine where they sat in the original String. Then you can take a substring for the delimiting character.

Bit dirty, but should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not sure what you are trying to do, but if \n has a different meaning
than " ", you should deal with them separately.

```
String[] sentences = text.split("\\n");
...
for (String sentence : sentences) {
    ...
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    ...
}
```